# Using a USB adapter inside an enclosure?

Tags: adapter, enclosure

I want to make a device that uses AC 220-250V power (to control relays to switch devices on/off) and prefer a single wire (+/-/gnd) to a wall socket box (thus not a separate 5V adapter).

Would it be a strange to use a 5V USB adapter inside an enclosure like below?
I hid the top cover of the enclosure and put a yellow box around it for better viewability.
I'm intending to get the AC power inside through a hole or connector and directly 'solder' it to the two long socket pins of the USB adapter.
Note that the GX connector will not be used for 220V AC (I will use an IEC connector or cut a hole in the box as I connect/screw it to a power strip.

The reason is that I'm not that good into electronics and creating my own AC ->5V DC power supply including all needed protection seems a bit hard.

[image]

Comment: It wouldn't be terribly unusual for a one-off DIY project to be built this way. Who cares about "strange"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're not comfortable designing a mains -> \$5~\mathrm{V_{dc}}\$ convertor (understandable), then there are plenty of modules that you can get, rather than bodging in an adaptor with pins. You can get them in a wide range of capacities and sizes. They won't be as cheap as just picking up no-name 5 V adaptor, but will be a better fit for an application like yours. In particular, you will know the supply specifications and form factor.

A [potted module](https://uk.farnell.com/myrra/48022/power-supply-ac-dc-5v-0-6a/dp/2776637):
[image: Potted module from Farnell]

An [open frame module](https://uk.farnell.com/mean-well/mfm-10-5/power-supply-ac-dc-5v-2a/dp/3002875):
[image: Open frame PSU from Farnell]

Comment: Thanks I like the potted one, as I like the plastic box around it, just in case.

Comment: I once had an idea of making a power supply for vacuum tubes using 40-ish USB adapters in series. I decided against doing  it.